# VLC video playback when playing just audio

Tags: vlc-media-player

In VLC is it possible to make it so that for files that are just music (mp3, FLAC specifically) are played and the "video" part of the screen is the song title/album/artist?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need the track info to display on the monitor? There may be other solutions depending on what you are going for.

Comment: No, not really, but I have been considering buying a second monitor and my VLC window would go on there, along with IRC and a terminal or something.

Comment: I challenge you to see how long you can go before you put something besides VLC, IRC, and a terminal on your shiny new second monitor, ha.

Comment: It'll be a cheap low quality monitor in addition to my laptop. So I'll probably have to stretch windows quite a bit for legibility...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. VLC's video window and general UI is centered around video, not audio, and doesn't provide those kinds of features.

The filename will appear in the title bar; so it's there if your files have descriptive names. The album art, if embedded in the file, will display in the video area.

If you are in the playlist view you can see the current track highlighted. Other than that VLC isn't really the right tool for the job.

On Linux consider something like rhythmbox or xmms. On Windows consider WinAmp/Media Player/iTunes. On Mac, iTunes of course. These applications are designed with audio in mind.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a way to do just that, but it's a bit of a workaround and requires some image editing. The basic idea is building the info you want into an album artwork.

If the music doesn't have an album artwork yet, you can just place text into a picture. I recommend using a perfect square as the canvas -- while VLC can handle non-square album art, it will usually distort everything non-square into a square. Just put the image next to the music files and VLC should pick it up as the album artwork.

If it does have album artwork, things are a bit more complicated. You would start by removing the existing album artwork with your ID3 editor of choice. This alone will only remove the album artwork from VLC if you didn't open music from that album with VLC yet, because VLC caches album artwork. You can easily find the location of the cached album artwork by opening the music file, then saving the playlist to a file, and then editing the playlist file with a text editor (VLC uses XSPF playlists by default). The location of the album artwork should be in the `image` tag of the respective track list element (which will be just that one file unless you used an existing playlist, in which case you need to identify the right entry).

Once you located the cached entry, you have 2 options. You can replace the cached image with your custom album artwork that contains the ID3 info as text (as well as the existing album artwork if you want, obviously). Or you can just delete the file (or move it to a non-VLC location) and proceed as if there had never been an album artwork to begin with. I haven't really tried how VLC behaves if you place non-square artwork in its cache, so with the second option you should be on the safer side.